# Android Complex Xml Parsing

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Please anyone suggest me how to parse this complex xml data .I have tried by

many way but i am unable to get profile and server tag which is inside

profiles.I tried by this link http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-

xml-parsing-tutorial/

Thanks in advance for your code and lovely suggestion .Please help me....

```
<analec>
<emails>
<email regex="*@analec.com" profilId="1" order="1"/>
</emails>
<profiles>
<profile name="ANALEC ClientManager (AWS)" ID="1">
<server name="AWS Host" order="1" endpoint="https://ec2-54-191-187-206.us-    
 west-  2.compute.amazonaws.com/" ssl="true" ignoreSSLErrors="true"/>
<server name="AWS IP" order="2" endpoint="https://54.191.187.206/" 
ssl="true"  ignoreSSLErrors="false"/>
</profile>
</profiles>
</analec>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use pull parser. Android recommends to use XMLPullParser to parse the xml file than SAX and DOM because it is fast.

follow this link : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-XMLPullParser-tutorial ,

hope it helps